# Enabling SPDY for nginx as reverse proxy to Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-wsgi, spdy

I am running nginx as a reverse proxy to apache (with mod_wsgi for a django app). nginx also serves static files. If I enable spdy on nginx, do I need to enable spdy on apache too to get maximum benefit of spdy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. SPDY is supposed to bring speed enhancements over high latency networks by more efficiently using the TCP connections and multiplexing HTTP communication through single TCP connections, as well as offering better compression and encodings support. If you run nginx as a reverse proxy on the same machine as the Apache server then you definitely will not see a big improvement on using SPDY on the backend (well, it doesn't mean you can't optimize speed between nginx and Apache by other means, including using Keep Alive and so on).

Answer (score 1):

SPDY will (probably) speed up your static-file-access, bot for your app you wouldnt see much improvement. if possible, server your static-file via static.example.com, enable SPDY on that server and disable SPDY on your app-server (esp when using proxy_cache); SPDY ist still experiemntal, and there the are [some issues](https://www.mare-system.de/guide-to-nginx-ssl-spdy-hsts/#spdy)